# MockHttpServletResponse body empty

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit5

I try to test my method `addPerson()` in my controller, but when I execute the test I have status 200 with an empty body in `MockHttpServletResponse`. I would like to test the body response with `jsonPath` from `MockMvcResultMatchers` but I can't do it while the body is empty.

Here is my test:

```
@WebMvcTest(PersonController.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class PersonControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private Model model;

    @MockBean
    private PersonService service;

     @Test
     public void addPersonTest() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(post("/person/add")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content("{\"firstName\": \"Test\",\"lastName\": \"\",\"address\": \"\",\"city\": \"\",\"zip\": \"\",\"phone\": \"\",\"email\": \"\"}"))
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
     }
```

Here is my controller with the method addPerson()

```
@RequestMapping("/person")
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    Model model;

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getRootLogger();

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<Person> allPerson() {
        return personService.all();
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public List<Person> addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        List<Person> listPerson = this.personService.add(person);

        logger.info("Request = @RequestBody = {}", person);
        logger.info("Response {}", listPerson);
        return listPerson;
    }
```

And here is the service:

```
@Service
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private Model model;

    public PersonService(Model model2) {
         this.model = model2;
    }

    public List<Person> add(Person person) {
        List<Person> listPersons = model.getPersons();
        listPersons.add(person);
        return listPersons;
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you are mocking PersonService with the @MockBean annotation, you are causing the service to not call the actual method and is returning an empty list.  Also your add method will not work as you're expecting as it doesn't save the list back to your model.

Answer (score 0):

As you mock the `PersonService` you have to provide its behaviour otherwise it always returns `null`. You can use `when().thenReturn()` from Mockito for this:

```
@WebMvcTest(PersonController.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class PersonControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private Model model;

    @MockBean
    private PersonService service;


     @Test
     public void addPersonTest() throws Exception {

           List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(new Person()); // create list here
           when(service.add(any(Person.class)).thenReturn(personList); // mock the behaviour of your PersonService bean

           this.mvc.perform(post("/person/add")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content("{\"firstName\": \"Test\",\"lastName\": \"\",\"address\": \"\",\"city\": \"\",\"zip\": \"\",\"phone\": \"\",\"email\": \"\"}"))
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
     }
}
```

Comment: if i have another service inside PersonService should i mock that inner service too?

Comment: By mocking `PersonService`, you don't need to care about the internals of this class and there's no need/value mocking classes of a mock.